# android bitbucket pipleine build ./gradlew assembleQADebug failure but local build works?

Tags: android, gradle, bitbucket, android-safe-args

I enabled the pipleline and created the bitbuket-pipelines.yaml for my android project in bitbucket repo.

The pipeline build seems started fine and I can see the gradle tasks are being executed in the output console, just like executing the same gradlew build on my local machine:

./gradlew assembleQADebug

however, one of the task failed in the bitbucket cloud, I read the error, it is for the Jetpack Navigigation component SafeArgs:

```
...
> Task :app:compileQADebugKotlin
e: /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/.../AaaFragment.kt: (71, 86): Unresolved reference: actionAbcFragment
e: /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/.../XxxFragment.kt: (73, 86): Unresolved reference: actionZzzFragment
e: ...
```

Any tips or guess how to find out why this works in local but failed in fail in bitbucket pipleline?

The following is my simple yaml file:

```
image: androidsdk/android-31

pipelines:
  branches:
    playground/bitbucketbuild:
    - parallel:
        - step:
            name: Build Android
            memory: 2048
            caches:
              - gradle
            script:
              - cd $PROJ_ROOT && ./gradlew assembleQADebug #- ./gradlew clean bundleQARelease
              - echo $PWD && ls -R app/build/outputs
    - step:           # step to run unit tests
        name: Unit Tests
        caches:
          - gradle
        script:
          - cd $PROJ_ROOT && ./gradlew test
```